# React.js How to pass a variable from another js file that does not have export

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an autogenerated fairly large js file that its content is just one big variable like this:

```
ConstDef.js:
var ConstantDefinitions = {
variable1: "blahbalhbalh",
variable2: "blahBlahBlah",
...
variable10000: "BlahbluuBleh"
}
```

How can I access the contents of this file in React.js?
If I add `export {ConstantDefinitions}` manually at the bottom of `ConstDef.js`, I can easily write something like:

```
import { ConstantDefinitions } from './ConstDef';

const defHelper = {
  getStringByKey(key) {
    const def = ConstantDefinitions [key];
    return def;
  }
};

export default defHelper ;
```

My plan B is to write a script to somehow append `export {ConstantDefinitions}` to my autogenerated file, However, I am trying to access that object without manipulating the source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best method is to add export to your generator.

But as you have var variable in your file you can choice completely wrong(but workable) path. You can access to your variable because it stored in global scope. https://www.javatpoint.com/javascript-global-variable

```
import './youPathToVariable';
...
window.ConstantDefinitions
...
```

Also(as @Umberto mentioned in his answer) you can generate json file)

Answer (score 3):

You could generate a Json File instead of a JS Object, and import it from React Component